# KineticJS rotating/animating text

Tags: animation, kineticjs

I have this fiddle where I have text arranged in a circle, I would like now to animate it and rotate the text in a clockwise/counter clockwise motion.

Every animation demo I have seen uses a  container as the starting point however all the examples i could find about manipulating text in a circular arrangement have all started with the  element. I have tried 100's of variations trying to get this working but I am either missing something or it's not possible with the construction i have used thus far.

Here is the fiddle for the circular text I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/jamesburt/Sa2G8/

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
```

Where as the animation examples start off with:

```
<div id="container"></div>
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({container: 'container'});
```

I'm open to any ideas / rewrites needed as ultimately my goal is an animated text circle. 
Also if this is easily accomplished in an alternative to KineticJS I'd be interested in trying that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo I made using KineticJS: http://jsfiddle.net/Moonseeker/Xf7hp/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 500,
    height: 500
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var myText = "My text in a circle. ";
var centerCoords = {x:250, y:250};

for(var i=0;i<myText.length;i++){
    var rotation = i*360/myText.length;
    var oneChar = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: centerCoords.x,
        y: centerCoords.y,
        text: myText[i],
        fontSize: 30,
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        fill: 'green',
        offset: {x:0, y:100},
        rotationDeg: rotation
    });
    layer.add(oneChar);
}

// add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);

var angularSpeed = Math.PI / 2;
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame){
    var angleDiff = frame.timeDiff * angularSpeed / 1000;
    for(var i=0;i<layer.children.length;i++){
        layer.children[i].rotate(angleDiff);
    };
}, layer);
anim.start();
```

You can rotate at every direction or speed you wish, you can change the style of the circle.

You should be able to use `layer.find('Text').each()` instead of the for-loop for looping through the text to rotate but the KineticJS library at jsfiddle seems outdated as it doesn't know the find method.

Comment: I couldn't get the fiddle to run on two different machines... I took the code to http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/ and replaced one of the examples with it fired right up, I tried from two machines so not sure what was going on. But it works and is rotating.

Comment: So it worked on html5canvastutorials?
Watch the console for errors when you can't get it to work. You might have older libs or even a missing library.

Answer (score 0):

One efficient way:

- Render your text-around-a-circle on an offscreen canvas.
- Save that offscreen canvas as an image using .toDataURL
- Create a Kinetic.Image from that offscreen image.
- You can then efficiently rotate/animate the Kinetic.Image as you need.